# A question regarding lebesgue stieljes measure in 2 dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying a problem that  is based on lebesgue stieljes measure in 2 dimensions. I could not solve it part although I tried manipulating Right hand side several times. Actually I am confused where to use $ x_i $ $ \le $ $ y_i $  , if i= 1,2 . 
Question is - If X : $ R^2 $---> R and F: $ R^2 $  --->R . 
Then prove monotonicity ie
if x= ( $x_1$ ,$ x_2$) and y= ( $y_1$,$y_2$ ) and  $ x_i $ $ \le $ $ y_i  $  for i = 1,2 
Then prove that $ \delta $ F(x, y) = F($ y_1$, $ y_2 $) 
+ F($ x_1$, $ x_2$) - F( $ x_1$, $ y_2 $) - F( $ y_1$, $x_2$) is always $\ge  $ 0 .

Can some one please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu$ is a finite measure on the Borel sigma algebra of  $\mathbb R^{2}$ abd $F(x,y)=\mu((-\infty,x]\times (-\infty,y])$ then $F(y_1,y_2)+F(x_1,x_2)-F(x_1,y_2)-F(y_1,x_2)$ is nothing but $\mu ((x_1,y_1]\times (x_2,y_2])$. To see this write $(x_1,y_1]$ as the difference of $(-\infty,y_1]$ and $(-\infty,x_1]$ and $(x_2,y_2]$ as the difference of $(-\infty,y_2]$ and $(-\infty,x_2]$

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy Thank you